# Why does typescript infer a generic as {} if the callback parameters don't have an explicit type here

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a config that has columns (a tuple) and a callback.

```
export type FooConfig<
    T extends { [N in keyof T]: VerifyFoo<T[N]> },
> = {
    columns: T & readonly Foo<any, any, any>[]
    transformRows?: (
        columns: T,
    ) => any
};
```

The columns tuple has objects of the following shape:

```
export interface Foo<
    TData extends GenericData,
    TVariables extends GenericVariables,
    TFilter,
> {
    query: DataType<TData, TVariables>
    filterFieldName?: TFilter
}
```

All of this is put together in the following function:

```
function create<T extends { [N in keyof T]: VerifyFoo<T[N]> },>(t: FooConfig<T>) {
    return t;
}
```

```
// inferred generic type is {}
create({
    transformRows: (columns) => {

    } ,
    columns:       [
        {
            query: "" as unknown as DataType<queryOne, queryOneVariables>,
        },
        {
            query:           "" as unknown as DataType<queryTwo, queryTwoVariables>,
            filterFieldName: 'idA',
        },
    ]} as const
);
```

The issue is that if the transformRows is not defined in the config the create function works correctly it thorws an error if `filterFieldName` is inncorrect and the generics contains all the data about columns. However when I add the `transformRows` callback it breaks and infers `{}` as the type of the generic for the create function.

What has me confused is that intellisense seems to work:

[image: intellisense works but ts error]

Furthermore if I manually type `transformRows`, like this:

```
transformRows: (columns: string) => {},
```

it gives a type error that the string type cannot be assigned to the generic and print the exact type I want (the error message is very long you can try it yourself on TS playground). I've tried using the `NoInfer` from `ts-toolbelt` but was unsuccessful.

How could I do this to get all the data about the columns, check `filterFieldName` field, and infer the type of `transformRows` ?

[TS playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEFkHkGEGlQCIEEAqTQDFICVQoKIDKKAkgHIDiAUFQKYAeADgPYBOALqOwJ6O2gBHAK61W3SADtaANQCGrAJayARgBtaAZ1ABeUAG8aoUADMFq9qI0AufQoAmJGxvaKJAcwC+NDwG4aDFg4uXn5hUXEpEgsAWy1dAwBIVlpZO2YJVW5BETFJWjJZaNoAficXBXdQAB9QCSFVVQAaKiSUtIyssNzIu1LQZ1c3atr6pqovOiY2Th4+bPC8nX0W5NT0zNAFGI0+7Db17iRWVlluAB4uiNoo2ljhuoaAPnvR8b9JwJmQ+bEUAHdmHJFCp1HFllQjKZzJYbHp7EgyoMJkYAMZCVgaNiIipDGoPVTvXz+KZBWahHLcf7MG53eIrfYdH6UgEoEJ9AY4l4NZqtNaMy4kXrYyp40bNCYBabBOaXKlLRKrdobLa3HY2PZ8zJHE7nWUAmlaUVPLmqN40KggUAkLiKWh2UB-E6MRiclAOrYAC1AZGpEmMolAyiEMw9sk4KND7jttWY7A9OI+UrJ3t9-tYZ3QDAsEjsWlkEm4z20EKMoAA2kgALoV0BZ2g5vMF0DFUAABlANikADdRJWaJaUABNAAKRBoyYQYdkrL4ZxQk-YskaeCBSjUmiLy1LoDsU5s86nJaMXfka9B+9XIM042Jn2l-GkogUxm4GGYzDnRZabrrDcw77OCo00QZcgIDaRlyECQAGsJGYP4JGeYoWgSN8PwQZcINAaDaG4ZhjBTCQyFGK8zh9IiSPXM5pEeMsAHIoQsDE6MrR5nk7Wge1Yd5JVJb4KHrJ8UQXWR5RaFVYj6RUDlAfNuDLSsTTNRM+LmASpEUFFL3XMFEkYmFQD2FE2DsM4OXcZc5OeGooLsWhTCke0jVNBJLnZcoRRGBplN4zgKiY4xZBRfg0LOb8RNrehs1zUB1KEkSeRQbTQUi6KtDizTks0RKMDMJjmmeRJLhsESZ1oOcEpXU8rw0R4Wn01hctoVQ7AKIo+hQXLoVYG8VK+OY0OgdJTDcMKEh-KL6xivRyzITYJGw3D8LwSsbEfRQX1ClAyzIVjQA8AqxISYzVCEaIJGsPBQAAMlAaTGVCuTLILZ7CwUloXHzDRjDYaJsHgtVQAAChQk6zou-ceQASh0Z45OU4woJRdgFHSUAUVWCw51SqatBmnb5sWvCCJQVbQHW59XwA7bdueA7HiB9gbEG4aFFGlBHhhgxt2Sdh0QW9g-AmDGUgsIHEgHeMtABVhoK0YzjloZHMmXOM2D+Rta2ONhNgIhqmpatr+AULQKgkBXkmR2Scy4D1+AyhQUXl9JFwqPMGlt-hd0XWTlGYYN0eYU7zo0I9A+DiHt1LMsw+3bmo4T4rQAAImAZPZK0KDYPghbZC0UqQguCk8mXS48iy2rmgTowDtj0t4+r0sk8boxU-TvPQCzuCEIzxApzKovwipUuKSpCvHirlvITy0QDdawpaBsOj4ToyeE9r7dKw8XvjIu9gqCh94RbDWhxZaS0fT+T30cx-g3EEzTNlNv1RGjDu9G3v54wjQNVjl2suLcDjAmBIn0Lo-VYH9AGNggZgxDjDbQhUaAJG3mvcO4NLoJxjo3BuLck7J3bpnGC3dc7537oXMuUgR4LCkOPNB24N7V1wY3ZuLcCG9y7jnXuBdZx6mYNQ34AI6F1wTvrBQzV55FCXivehpZGFGC3jvdIzgD4+CAA)

Comment: Ugh, who knows? Inferring both generic types and callback param types in the same object with complicated type inference-juggling constraints isn't something that can be done reliably.  I see the fallback to `{}` as an inference failure that for some reason isn't being reported as an error (if you add a second generic type parameter, you'll see the issue [more clearly](https://tsplay.dev/mL3DVN)).  Personally I would stop fighting the type system and refactor to another approach entirely, but I don't know if that kind of answer would be well-received. If so I could think about it more.

Comment: Considering the actual code I am working on has two more generics on Foo<> makes me think that I should probably refactor if this hits typescript limits

Comment: @jcalz how would you refactor this ? Passing generic values fails since then you have to pass all of them

Comment: You could change `create()` to be a curried function as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NdE9vm), for example... anything "builder" like that accepts things in chunks the compiler can handle would suffice.  Does that make sense? I could write that up as an answer I guess

Comment: @jcalz An interesting approach, I kind of already settled on the user passing in the generics, not the cleanest solution but works for now. I ll try what you suggested here when I have a bit more time. Thank you

Comment: Would you like me to write up an answer with the refactoring as a suggestion?

Comment: @jcalz That would be nice yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's algorithm for inferring [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type arguments and for [contextually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) inferring unannotated function parameters isn't perfect by any means.  Without a full [unification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science)) algorithm as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30134](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30134), there will always be situations where inference fails despite there existing a "correct" set of types that should have been inferred.  The situation has been steadily improving (e.g., [TS4.7 improved function inference in objects and methods](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-7.html#improved-function-inference-in-objects-and-methods)), and there are tricks and tips you can use to try to lead inference in a desired direction, but sometimes it just won't work.

This may be one of those times (at least I wasn't able to find something better).

---

In situations like this, it is sometimes preferable to work around the problem and  refactor your code so that inference succeeds.  One way to do this is via a [fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern), where instead of calling the function all at once, you do it in chunks and in an order where each chunk relies only on successful inference from previous chunks.

For example, we can break `create()` into pieces, to become a function which first accepts only `columns`, and then returns another function that accepts `transformRows`.  The `columns` input can be used to infer the generic type argument `T` (and if not, you could imagine breaking this up into a series of calls where each one accepts a key and a value)... and so by the time you call the second function the compiler definitely knows what type the callback parameter to `transformRows` will be.  Like this:

```
const create = <T extends { [N in keyof T]: VerifyFoo<T[N]> },>(
    columns: T & readonly Foo<any, any, any>[]) =>
    (transformRows?: (columns: T) => any) => ({ columns, transformRows });
```

This ends up creating the same object as before.  Let's test it:

```
const x = create([
    {
        query: "" as unknown as DataType<queryOne, queryOneVariables>,
    },
    {
        query: "" as unknown as DataType<queryTwo, queryTwoVariables>,
        filterFieldName: 'idA',
    },
] as const)((columns) => {
    /* (parameter) columns: readonly [{
    readonly query: DataType<queryOne, queryOneVariables>;
}, {
    readonly query: DataType<queryTwo, queryTwoVariables>;
    readonly filterFieldName: "idA";
}] */    
});

/* const x: {
    columns: readonly [{
        readonly query: DataType<queryOne, queryOneVariables>;
    }, {
        readonly query: DataType<queryTwo, queryTwoVariables>;
        readonly filterFieldName: "idA";
    }];
    transformRows: ((columns: readonly [{
        readonly query: DataType<queryOne, queryOneVariables>;
    }, {
        readonly query: DataType<queryTwo, queryTwoVariables>;
        readonly filterFieldName: "idA";
    }]) => any) | undefined;
} */
```

Looks good!  Inference works as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/PTAEFkHkGEGlQCIEEAqTQDFICVQoKIDKKAkgHIDiAUFQKYAeADgPYBOALqOwJ6O2gBHAK61W3SADtaANQCGrAJayARgBtaAZ1ABeUAG8aoI6ABmC1e1EaAXPtAKAJiVsb2iiQHNQAXxreA3DQMLBxcvPzCouJSJJYAtlq6BsagrLSyDswSqtyCImKStGSycbQA-C5uCp6gAD6gEkKqqgA0VClpGVk5eVGFJA4VoK7uXvWNzW2+dExsnDx8vQVSOvrtxp2Z2bkK8RpD2OlbOUisrLLcADyRy7SxtAl1DU2qAHxPE6pUAUGzoQsRfLcFAAd2YckUKnUiTW6yMZgsVlsensDiQlVGPkMxgAxkJWBo2BjqmNns1At8KcE5mFFjdgWD7o8knDUkdurl6aDmChwkMRiSPi82h12dsltwBvyqjVxsLvr8QvNwhLuatkhsxT1dg99rZDl1tqdzlcuYy9kLmu85c1KTQqCBQCQuIpaA5QCDzoxGIKUB7dgALUBkZgkCQmUSgZRCeYB2ScHFxzxuhrMdgBkkzJW0-ghsMR1iXdAMSwSBxaWQSbjvbSsgDaSAAug3QCXaGWK1XQGVQAAGUC2KQAN1EjZojpQAE0AApEGgAxDx2S8viXFAIJctPAQpRqTQ1tYpBxL2zrpesofyXfQ087qGaBVZmkL6SiBQmbgYZjMNc11l+tsO0wb9LmqAtEC3MDI2kLchAkABrCRmBBCR3jKVkvx-BAtxg0B4NobhmBMYMsjIF570uEMJDI5oKOkV46wAcgRSwCUYxtXneQdaBHVgqT+ZVFgods3xxDd2FkdVWR1BIhk2DlQErbg60bS0vh+J9-hVYSpEUHE7z3GENXhcxWJsUBDhxNgHEuAVPC3JTrVAOCHFoMwpHdG0vhSelpUxLy7U0zhqlYkxZBxfhMMuf9xMkwDy1AHTRNikVjBQAzoVbehSwSpK9IyzRUqMFAMFM0Q2neYyJVsWKV1oNcUu3K97w0V5WRY0RStoVQHGKUohhKsrWEfaktMWTDoCyMwPGilIAOy9sEpROsyHsCQ8IIoi8EbWxX0UD8opQFaOJ8CqpJSKzVCEOIJHMv0ADI2UNHooqUhyq3e6sVNZNxKw0Ew2DibBkL1UAAApWQu5grpuu6itAABKHR3iUwKrNuhNOksVY1yynKtGW1bqg2wjiJQHbQD299PxAo6yBO7wWleCGoZh27T1AR75PFV6PsUvnHJUpHtDalIwd+26AdYIGQaGMHLuu9m8GFlGqxV8GUQV2HbC127FK0FAtwl-7AeBkEtG8BGKXR1xQHoVYcSx2gwbrVkqp8oFbAAIi9-XnIQpCUL92rwmuIFCi3elCgK1r4cZt3IeMelvd92QtDgxDkPWtPFwkuqw6iblI6BbkY9eeGUg61gup6vraFsRjHCQRi47aVSc5t9gEbB+XocVjR1aq4AACpwcYeQSloVikd18zuZ6OsqvnzlPdz5dQ6jqRi76KQy8CRnD01Z6V6iGql3zs1mG3sRS+awzXkCUVj9MIaa96yfvabr399U4fgD8K245R6dztsiVks9bDL1AIvRORgoHJzXhfcOW8JTRzvtCB+rID7uyPscE+Ygz55w3iXME18GTgnQfuR+KRcEKSrm-Oun80TfywY2ahRhjZSxlubWwPcIFPTwdAnBcCtT4O4IQ9eq5N60DIWgyE992GnUPjQgRCkEEhykSQq+qowR71gao8U9CFDdXfqUJhSAWEpG8I2dWSkkb1Bcm5aobp96gD-kAA)